# How to use Repository without associate to an Entity class in symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, repository, entity

I would like logic like the following:
-> controller- > call to Model class (that extend model with the entity,manager)- > the function in model will call to getRepository() and use funcion that dealing with the DB.

How can I do that? When I call to Repository I must have an entity, and if I have an empty entity the error is that I must have primary column with id.

Comment: Entities shouldn't use repositories! That's against a few patterns and good practicies.

Comment: ^ what he says. Please let us know *what* you want to do, and maybe we've got a better idea *how* you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment says, you should not call the repository directly from the entity class. You have several options here (descending by the code quality)

### Refine the logic to invert the control flow

Define a service, which accepts the entity, the repository and does the stuff

```
$service = new EntityStuffService($repository);
$service->doTheStuff($entity);
```

### Declare a relation

Just declare a realtion within your class and filter it manually. Doctrine `PersistentCollection` implements `Selectable`, so you can just filter it using the `->matching($criteria)` call.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

### The ugliest way

Doctrine has the `ObjectManagerAware` interface, which allows you to inject the object manager into the entity on hydation completion. This will allow you to implement and kind of AR patters and other spaghetti-code and I strongly recommend you not to do this.

https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ObjectManagerAware.php

You can implement this interface and store the `ObjectManager` inside the entity to do any kind of operations with it.